# syntax error on line 15, col 2: ` socket: /tmp/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets

Hello World ( stackoverflow ) !

I started up my server, and I'm getting this :

```
Started GET "/demo/hello" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Jan 18 16:42:42 -0500 2011

ArgumentError (syntax error on line 15, col 2: `  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock'):
```

**My database.yml**

```
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Those match.. so I checked my sockets in mysql..

```
    mysql> show variables like 'socket';
    +---------------+-----------------+
    | Variable_name | Value           |
    +---------------+-----------------+
    | socket        | /tmp/mysql.sock |
    +---------------+-----------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So it's the right sockets...maybe its permissions?

```
mysql -u root -ppassword -h localhost my_database
```

Logs in, no problems.

I'm using the following:

mysql -v = 5.1.54
rails -v = 3.0.3
ruby -v = 1.8.7

Stumped! Any ideas what I may be missing?

Comment: I totall just read that error message as having two parts: `ArgumentError (syntax error on line 15, col 2: '  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock'` and `):` -- like the parser was sad about this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means there is a yaml syntax error. Usually it's a stray tab (make sure you don't have any tabs in that area of the yaml file -- delete all the whitespace and enter spaces just to be sure). If that's not the problem, it could be antoher syntax issue (if so, please paste your whole yaml file -- masking any sensitive information of course).

Comment: Do'h! you know what it was? I didn't have a space between the `:` and the password! Also big ups and making sure if I posted my .yml I couldn't pull a stupid ;) Thanks so much!